# asyncio streams check if reader has data

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

So I want to implement a simple comms protocol where reads & writes are completely asynchronous. That means that client sends some data and then server may or may not respond with an answer. So I can't just call `reader.read()` because that blocks until at least something is returned. And I may have something more to send in the mean time.

So is there a way to check if reader has something to read? 
(please note that I'm talking specifically about the streams version: I'm fully aware that protocols version has separate handlers for reading and writing and does not suffer from this issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to ask reader has incoming data or not.

I guess to create `asyncio.Task` for reading data from asyncio stream reader in loop.
If you need to write data asynchronously feel free to call `StreamWriter.write()` from any task that have some outgoing data.

I strongly dont recommend to use protocols directly -- they are low-level abstraction useful for flow control but for application code is better to use high-level streams.